# Optix Denoiser Not working in Renders

Tags: rendering, denoise

I have an RTX 2070 Super with Amd 3700x.

I have optix enabled and it denoises the viewport render which is fine. However when I go to render out the image it begins denoising on the second pass and looks fine, but when the render finishes the noise comes back to the image as if it hadn't been denoised despite the denoiser working until it finished.

I have tried turning alternating with cuda on and off on gpu and cpu in the preferences as well as changing the passes to color and albedo with and without normals. I cant seem to find any answer for this problem online, I will keep looking in the meantime. But if anyone has any idea what might be going on I would greatly appreciate the help.

[image: render on second pass without noise]
render on second pass without noise

[image: finished noisy render]
finished noisy render

Comment: did you connect the nodes in the compositor?

Comment: Isn't the denoiser node for the Intel denoiser? or for Optix as well? I'm confused here.

Comment: Hey Susu, I downloaded 2.9 and the issue seems to have gone, the link you shared did help clarify a few things though so thank you. I haven't done too much rendering before so I will need to read up on denoising and denoise nodes as I dont think Optix works so well for animation! Thanks again for the help.

Comment: @ - nocan-do I don't think nodes work for Optix, that seems to be a separate thing than using nodes for Intel denoiser. I think my issue may have been a bug from an older version of blender.